# Web.config file can not take WebApi Project Url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

[image]

The above image is my web.config file.

[image]

I have two projects, the second project is my  webapi project as show in second image.

I gave the webapi project url in web.config and called controller, it work perfectly in local but when I upload it to the server and give path of my hosting server in web.config it doesn't call any controller and doesn't return response.

Any idea about it?

Comment: What "called controller" ? Do you request that url from a controller or from javascript or from where? Can you show us the code?

Comment: all controller call from webapi project client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("clienttype").Result;
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ClientTypeModel>>().Result;     baseAddress is     webapi project and it work perfectly in local

Comment: may main project call webapi project base on web.confige file   when host my webapi project on server then i   change url in web confige file but not give responce

Comment: plz anyone find  what mistake i was did?

Comment: i have two separate project one is asp.net mvc 4  and second is webapi  project  its run on local  but  on server not working  webapi give 500 no. error